# Populate dropdown in template from model choices using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have the model, serializer, viewset and html as follows:

```
GENDER = (
    ('MALE', 'Male'),
    ('FEMALE', 'Female'),
    ('OTHERS', 'Others'),
)

class Client(BaseModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="", blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="", blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, null=True, blank=True)


class ClientSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, "first_name", "") + " " + getattr(obj, "last_name", "")

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Client
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer

    @action(detail=True,  methods=['post','get'], renderer_classes=[renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer])
    def update_client(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = self.get_object()
        context = {"operation": "Update",
                   "object_id": object.id,
                   "events": Event.GetEventsForObject(object)}
        template_name = 'contact-client.html'
        response = Response(context, template_name=template_name)


<form id="client-form" method="" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" operation="{{operation}}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns medium-5 medium-text-left">
          <div class="select2-full select-2-full--sm input-rounded">
            <label for = "gender" style="text-align: left;" >Gender</label>
            <select id="gender" class="js-select2 input-height-sm element-contact" name="gender" validated="false"></select>
            <option></option>
          </div>
          <div id="gender_error" style="display:none">
            <p class="help-text"> <span class="form-action-icon error-icon"></span>Please select gender.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns medium-5 medium-text-left">
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I instantiate the `ClientSerializer` in `shell` like this `ClientSerializer()` then that gender field is shown along with its choices. But I am not able to show it in the template. All the other fields are being passed correctly.

How can I populate the dropdown with the values of choices in template? What should I pass in the `option` tag to display the choices and send the data to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **ChoiceField** instead of CharField

Replace this line

```
gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, null=True, blank=True)
```

with this one

```
gender = models.ChoiceField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, null=True, blank=True)
```

To show all the choices in your template you can do something like this

```
from my_app.models import gender

context = {"choices" : gender}
response = Response(context,template_name)
```

And in template

```
{% for choice in choices %}
    <option value="{{ choice }}">{{ choice }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok. And how can I show the choices in the dropdown in template?

Comment: @user001 i have updated my answer now you look at it

Comment: Ok. Got it. I was confused because in the `response` object this was not being passed and I thought that `serializer` will pass the `choices`. I did not want to specify it explicitly from views. Guess this is the only way in this case.

Comment: @user001 can you mark it as the right answer or can give me an upvote on this. it would help me a lot.

Comment: Sure. If I dont get a better answer in sometime then I will mark this as the correct answer. For now I have upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the django-template then you can create a model form and pass that form as render context and then render that inside a form.

More on model form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: I am using the html `form` tag. Not `modelform`. How can I show it using `form` instead of `modelform`?